# I am unable to remove the unnecessary spaces or newlines after html tags in html file

Tags: tex4ht

Could anybody help me what file need to be updated to remove newlines/spaces after html tags in the html file after using tex4ht (htlatex) as per the below:

from:

```
span
class="cmr-9"
```

to:

```
span
```

Thanks
Prasad

Comment: Please provide a MWE. You could help the community to find bugs more easier. If it is easy to help, you increase the chance of help for your problem. Think about it. ;)

Comment: The markup has been lost so your question is not really understandable, but you ask about removing spaces but your example seems to show removing the `class` attribute?

Comment: Yes I have generated xhtml by using (htlatex sample.tex "xhtml") but which file has to be updated to format the tags of the converted html file

Answer (score 2):

Newlines are often inserted directly by `tex4ht` configurations, probably because it needs to prevent possible hyphenation. You can use `tidy` command to cleanup the html.

Because you haven't provided an example, there is small file `sample.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

Helo \textit{world}, \texttt{hello} again.

Příliš \textit{žluťoučký kůň úpěl} ďábelské ódy.
\end{document}
```

default conversion:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,charset=utf-8,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="sample.tex" /> 
<meta name="date" content="2015-05-12 14:47:00" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" >Helo <span 
class="ecti-1000">world</span>, <span 
class="ectt-1000">hello </span>again.
</p><!--l. 9--><p class="indent" >   Příliš <span 
class="ecti-1000">žlu</span><span 
class="ecti-1000">ťou</span><span 
class="ecti-1000">čk</span><span 
class="ecti-1000">ý ků</span><span 
class="ecti-1000">ň </span><span 
class="ecti-1000">úp</span><span 
class="ecti-1000">ěl </span>ďábelské ódy. </p> 
</body></html>
```

and conversion using [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) with this build file, `sample.mk4`:

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local process = filter{"cleanspan-nat", "fixligatures", "hruletohr"}
Make:htlatex()
Make:htlatex()
Make:match("html$",process)
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -asxhtml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
```

compile with

make4ht -u sample.tex

the result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />

  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
  "text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
  <meta name="originator" content=
  "TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
  <!-- xhtml,charset=utf-8,html -->
  <meta name="src" content="sample.tex" />
  <meta name="date" content="2015-05-12 14:49:00" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!--l. 7-->

  <p class="noindent">Helo <span class="ecti-1000">world</span>,
  <span class="ectt-1000">hello</span> again.</p><!--l. 9-->

  <p class="indent">Příliš <span class="ecti-1000">žluťoučký kůň
  úpěl</span> ďábelské ódy.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

you can run command

```
tidy -m -asxhtml -utf8 -q -i filename.html
```

by hand if you don't want to use `make4ht`

Comment: Is there any specific .4ht file for doing the formatting of the tags or cleanup  the attributes of the tags while using htlatex (htlatex sample.tex "xhtml")

Comment: @user19551 no, it is possible only using some cleaning command, such as `tidy`

Comment: but when I use tidy it is displaying that it is not recognized in console. Is there any software need to be installed.

Comment: @user19551 yes, you need to install HTML tidy, you can download it for Windows from http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#binaries if you use Linux, it should be in the package repos